# When creating a view it is taking me to the index view and not the created view

Tags: view, return, public

When creating a view inASP.NET MVC, I am creating a view in the homecontroller, but when i run that view it takes me to the default index view.

```
    public IActionResult AdoptPet()
    {
        return View();
    } This is where i am creating my view from and then I create a razor view and select which model class to use.
```

I am trying to create a view where the pets information is displayed